# HTML textText formatting in excel

Tags: html, vba, excel

Noob problem here. I needed to format some text some Excel cells containing content pulled from other cells. Thought an easy fix might be HTML. I found this need piece of code in another post (so not mine)

```vb
Sub Sample()
Dim Ie As Object

Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With Ie
    .Visible = False

    .Navigate "about:blank"

    .document.body.InnerHTML = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

    .document.body.createtextrange.execCommand "Copy"
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    .Quit
End With
End Sub
```

It worked super, but I ended up deciding to explore other options. Now, however, the macro is 'stuck in my Excel'. I can't for the love of me figure out where it is hiding, not in the macro list or anywhere that I can find in the VB interface. But it is still working in all sheets I pull up. I hate to have let some little creature loose in my spreadsheets, how do I kill it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Press: Alt + F11
2. Press: Control + F
3. Select: Current Project
4. Find what type: "sample"

I hope that works for you. Let me know if it doesn't.